# How to allow other site retrieve data from your site?

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel, laravel-4

> **Details**

I'm new to RESTful API & Laravel world.

But *"Every artist was first an amateur. - right ? "*
Let's get to the point.

I have 2 sites. Let's call it :

- `A`
- `B`

Website `B` have a a nice list if users table + all of its relation.

I want to allow website `A` to access website `B` and load those nice data.

I never done this. I assume that the logics are :

- Website `A` will need some kind of api_keys to access into website `B`.
- Then after the api_key match, website `B` will return the data back to website `A` as json file.
- Then, website `A` will receive that json file, and load them into HTML and display it.

Is my logic is even close ? Please - correct me if I am wrong. :)

Here is what I've tried

After doing some researches, I came across this [site](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api--net-29785). I really liked it. I finished it all way.
Now, I kind of get a sense of RESTful API a little more.

Then, I came across this [site](http://laravel.io/forum/10-29-2014-how-to-make-auth-to-api-rest-from-a-mobile-app). I found this

`filters.php`

```
Route::filter('api', function() {

    // Fetch a user record based on api key
    $user = User::where('api_key', '=', Input::get('api_key'))
                ->take(1)
                ->get();

    if ($user->count() > 0) {
        Auth::onceUsingId($user[0]->id); // Authorize the user for this one request
    } else {
        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
});
```

I notice the OP of this, stored `api_key` in users table.

My questions

- Do I need to do that like him ?
- Is this the only way to do it ?
- Is there a better/easier way to do this ?
- Rather than grab the api_key from the database, Can I just manually set it to a `random` number + text like this '21sdf364rt7y6r5ty1u28x1h8gt7yt2ert3654871' ?
- How long will the `api_key` be expire ? Is it even `expire` ? How do we know that ?

Again, my main `goal` is to allow website `A` to access the stuffs from website `B`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my logic is even close ?

Yes it close enough.

So, the main goal is to access the stuffs from website B. You decide whether stuff from B is restricted content or not.

If users that can access the stuff is limited, yes you need an api keys.

If content for site B is for public, you can just print json data without any required api keys like github does: https://api.github.com/users/github.

Comment: Do you know where I can start ? I tried to Google around for a while now, and I couldn't really find anything that related with `api_key`. :(